# Typescript : ESLint : Unsafe return of an any typed value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following chunk of code :

```
const createRecordMapping = () : unknown => mapper.createMap(Record, RecordDto)
  .forMember((d) => d.value,
    mapFrom((s) => GraphQLJSON.parseValue(s.value)));
```

Eslint error i am getting for it is :

> Unsafe return of an any typed value
> @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return

What am I missing here?

Comment: Either `d.value` or `GraphQLJSON.parseValue(s.value)` produces `any`. The linting rule you have forbids returning `any`.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote translates to this:

```
const createRecordMapping = (): unknown => mapper.createMap(Record, RecordDto)
  .forMember((d) => /*d.value, */mapFrom((s) => GraphQLJSON.parseValue(s.value)));
```

You probably wanted to chain the functions:

```
const createRecordMapping = (): unknown => mapper.createMap(Record, RecordDto)
  .forMember((d) => d.value)
  .mapFrom((s) => GraphQLJSON.parseValue(s.value) as unknown);
```

Also, the `GraphQLJSON.parseValue` probably does return `any` type, as it is parsing JSON.

Comment: "*The code you wrote translates to this*" no, it passes two arguments to `.forMembers` - the first one is `(d) => d.value` the second one is (the result of) `mapFrom((s) => GraphQLJSON.parseValue(s.value))`. I'm unfamiliar with the API, so I don't know if that's correct way to call `.forMembers` or if there is a `mapFrom` function but it's quite plausible that's the case. I'd definitely expect a very different error if that was incorrect - at the very least `mapFrom` wouldn't be recognised as a valid function if it's not defined or imported.

Comment: @VLAZ I am sorry but it is not, the `() => ...` translates to `function () { return ... }`. When you return values separated by `,` only the last one will be kept. The first is only executed. Usually used by minifiers.

Comment: Correction, the `(d) => d.value` function is thrown away any only `mapFrom(...)`, is kept. Parse value does not return a function and thus the whole thing breaks apart.

Comment: [This is not true](https://jsbin.com/bozipakati/edit?js,console). This *isn't* the comma operator, it's a simple function call. If you want comma operator, you need to surround these in `()` - > `fn((a, b))` will pass `b` into `fn`, while `fn(a, b)`, passes `a` as first argument, `b` as second.